# Как сложить два объекта

Tags: javascript, ооп

Что то я вообще запутался,  теперь сомневаюсь правильно ли я понимаю задачу. Задача такова "Создать объект, хранящий в себе отдельно числитель и знаменатель дроби, и следующие функции для работы с этим объектом.
Функция умножения 2-х объектов-дробей ". Я создал два обьекта. Теперь как я понимаю  мне нужно создать функцию которая берёт значение свойства первого объекта и свойство второго объекта. Но я сомневаюсь правильно ли я понял и как это правильно сделать и почему нельзя  сделать так

```js
function Fraction(upNumber,downNumber){
    this.upNumber = upNumber;
    this.downNumber = downNumber;
}
let firstNumber = Fraction(5,10);
let secondNumber = Fraction(2,15);

function multiFraction(obj1,obj2){
     let resultUpNumber = obj1[this.upNumber] * obj2[this.upNumber];
    let resultDownNumber = obj1[значение свойства downNumber] * obj2[значение свойства downNumber];
    alert(resultUpNumber);
}
multiFraction(firstNumber,secondNumber);
```

Comment: `console.log(firstNumber, secondNumber);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция создания объекта не правильно работает, подправил.

```js
function Fraction(upNumber,downNumber){
    return {upNumber:upNumber, downNumber:downNumber};
}
let firstNumber = Fraction(5,10);
let secondNumber = Fraction(2,15);

function multiFraction(obj1,obj2){
    let resultUpNumber = obj1.upNumber * obj2.upNumber;
    let resultDownNumber = obj1.downNumber * obj2.downNumber;
    alert(`${resultUpNumber}/${resultDownNumber}`);
}
multiFraction(firstNumber,secondNumber);
```